Settling foundation, gap forming under back door
1" gap forming between the bottom of a sliding door frame & the stone pavers on the stoop. The house was built in 1960s, on a slight hill. There is a back door that goes out to a stoop, then 4 stairs going down to the ground. 2 photos linked ... the gap is shallow with plastic siding visible behind it, but tall enough for all kinds of pests.
Recommendations?

Covering/filling in the gap is the easy part.  Is it the foundation setting/sinking or just that part/section under the door?  Is the gap moving/getting bigger?  Foundation setting should happen in the first 5 to 10 years, not after 50.
